# A Unique Invariant subspace for a set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, invariance

Im wondering if anyone can give me a good reference or answer this question which may have already be solved.

For a set of generic $n\times n$ matrices $A_1,A_2,...,A_k$, such that

1. they share only a SINGLE eigenvector in common,
2. the joint commutant of $A_1,A_2,...,A_k$ is trivial,

how can I guarantee there exists only this single one dimensional invariant subspace (corresponding to the span of that eigenvector)?

Googling around, it seems some progress has been made on saying whether invariant subspaces of dimension greater than 2 exist, but they rely on the fact that the matrices $A_1,A_2,...,A_k$ are chosen to have pairwise distinct eigenvalues.

I appreciate any help or direction! Thanks!

Comment: Does condition $2$ mean that no other matrix than multiples of the identity commute with all those matrices simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

The actual question isn't very clear; I am going to assume that question is to show that hypotheses 1 (which I take to mean the set of of common eigenvectors forms a one-dimensional subspace, with the zero vector removed) and 2 imply that there are no other one-dimensional common invariant subspace of these operators. Then the answer is simply that in general a one-dimensional subspace is an invariant subspace if and only if it is contained in an eigenspace. If there were another one-dimensional common invariant subspace, its elements would also be common eigenvectors of the operators, violating 1.

But I am probably misinterpreting something, since hypothesis 2 appears to be superfluous.